# How to access the service instance from host object in WCF?

Tags: wcf, adhoc, host-object

I am trying to incarnate some sort of ad hoc WCF service. I already managed to launch it and make it call its own web methods as some other guy's methods.

The issue that I am facing is instance management. I have set `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]` so it now has a global instance with the same properties for all clients.

But besides that I need it to call other services of its kind while listening to incoming requests from clients (similar crazy services).

While debugging I noticed that the ServiceHost's constructor calls the constructor of the service class. So, I assumed it has access to the global instance of this class and I need to find a way to call methods of this instance.

Please don't ask what I have been smoking, I just have to make it ad hoc.

Comment: ServiceHost's SingletonInstance is null .(.

Comment: OperationContext.Current is null too!

Comment: I was even trying to wait until `host.State == CommunicationState.Opened`, but even after that OperationContext.Current is still null

Comment: Ok. I got it. I created a service object first and then passed it to the ServiceHost's constructor.